# Malformed entry 11 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list on fresh TPU VM on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, apt-get, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I created a [TPU VM on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/users-guide-tpu-vm).

I logged in via ssh and want to install some software. But I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 11 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb {{mirror}} {{codename}} main restricted
# deb-src {{mirror}} {{codename}} main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb {{mirror}} {{codename}}-updates main restricted
# deb-src {{mirror}} {{codename}}-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb {{mirror}} {{codename}} universe
# deb-src {{mirror}} {{codename}} universe
deb {{mirror}} {{codename}}-updates universe
# deb-src {{mirror}} {{codename}}-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
[...]
```

What do I need to do to solve this?

Comment: are you sure  {{mirror}} {{codename}} values are set?

Comment: @Begging Where or how can I check if these values are set?

Comment: I'm not really sure why do you have placeholders there :smile: I guess your file should look like this https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/apt/sources.list_file, could you please try to replace maybe?

Comment: Sure I can replace them, but I want to understand why they are there in the first place on a fresh install. The comments mention `cloud-init ` so I am not sure if I need to run some program or something to get the file in the correct state.

Comment: I do not know the answer, but those variables look like template variables. I think you have discovered a bug in a Google procedure that creates those files. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Looks like you might be using the older version of the TPU VM image.

Two approaches -

1. If you still want to use your old VM, you can patch it with the following command -
   `sed -i 's+{{mirror}}+http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/+g;s+{{codename}}+focal+g;s+{{security}}+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu+g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Otherwise delete and recreate a new TPU VM that will fetch the latest image.